# JSON: how to deal with double quotations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, error-handling, sbjson

I'm using SBJson to parse by JSON string. Some requests return somethink like this:

```
{
"jsonResponse":[{  
"id":"2",  
"name":"Somename",  
"title":"Json problem:"ErrorParsing"", //problem is here. with double quotations. how to remove them or remove error? When i delete brackets before and after ErrorParsing, it works good.  
"otherinfo":"blabla",  
}]
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by double brackets. At any rate, that’s not a valid JSON string so it could be a problem in the Web service you’re using.

Comment: Double brackets it's brackets in brackets, something like: "Hello "World""

Comment: So this is Web service problem then. Thanks

Comment: Fixed the question. He didn't mean brackets but quotation marks.

Answer (score 4):

Those aren’t brackets; they’re (double) quotes/quotation marks. In valid JSON, quotation marks inside strings **must** be escaped with \, e.g. "Hello \"World\"".

The Web service you’re using is returning invalid JSON.

http://jsonlint.com is a useful resource to validate JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean "double quotes," not "double brackets." You'll need to use different quotes there, so something like:

```
"title":"Json problem:'ErrorParsing'"
```

Comment: I can't contol web response, i receive it, and I need to parse it:)

Comment: In that case (and in agreement with @Bavarious' answer), you're **not** receiving valid JSON. You'll need to work around this problem with the Web service.

Answer (score 0):

Correct json must be

```
{
"jsonResponse":[{  
"id":"2",  
"name":"Somename",  
"title":"Json problem:\"ErrorParsing\"", //problem is here. with double quotations. how to remove them or remove error? When i delete brackets before and after ErrorParsing, it works good.  
"otherinfo":"blabla",  
}]
}
```

I think you got the point